# jquery onclick span get whats inside span

Tags: jquery, html

Ok so i know that I can get a val() from input or select box, but how do I get what is inside a Span box. using Jquery?

I thought it could be `$('span#this').live('click', function(){ alert('#this').val()});`
but that did not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I would not use `this` as id, because `this` is a reserved JS word.

```
$('span.foo').live('click', function() {
    var content = $(this).html(); 
    // use content.
    alert(content);
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Regisc/qCsGU/

Answer (score 1):

Use `text()` or `html()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $('#this').html()
This will give you complete HTML markup inside your SPAN tag.

Answer (score 0):

in your code

```
alert('#this').val()
```

is incorrect

```
alert($('this').val())
```

is correct

and also use another word athor than `this` here `$('span#this')` because it is a reserved word